# How uncommenting jquery results in working of rails server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a new rails controller $ bin/rails generate controller welcome index
Modified my View

## Hello, Rails!

when I restarted my rails server, I faced the below issue.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Welcome#index
Showing /home/venkata/Downloads/app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/venkata/Downloads/app/app/assets/images
  /home/venkata/Downloads/app/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/venkata/Downloads/app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/venkata/Downloads/app/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/venkata/Downloads/app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
Rails.root: /home/venkata/Downloads/app
```

**Now when I uncomment the =require jquery in app/assets/javascripts** and restarted the server, got the expected output. wondering How this happens by uncommenting that particular line?

Comment: It is not a comment, it is requre statement.

Answer (score 1):

`//` is a comment but `//=` is not, `//= require jquery` includes the `jquery` library.

More info here - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths